Solr backup not getting created in both solr nodes
I have solr cloud version 9.5 with two nodes deployed in kubernetes cluster. I am trying to take solr backup using the Solr backup API
Bakup API -
http://localhost:8982/solr/admin/collections?action=BACKUP&name=dc0b1b5e-4333-42f0-8b1b-5e4333d2f084&collection=dc0b1b5e-4333-42f0-8b1b-5e4333d2f084&location=file:///var/solr/data/solr_backup
API Response:-
{
"responseHeader": {
"status": 0,
"QTime": 807
},
"response": {
"collection": "dc0b1b5e-4333-42f0-8b1b-5e4333d2f084",
"numShards": 1,
"backupId": 2,
"indexVersion": "9.9.2",
"startTime": "2024-06-27T06:31:11.765813769Z",
"indexFileCount": 127,
"uploadedIndexFileCount": 0,
"indexSizeMB": 0.187,
"extraProperties": {},
"uploadedIndexFileMB": 0.0,
"shardBackupIds": \[
"md_shard1_2"
\]
},
"success": {
"ds-solr-1.solr-headless.dctm-search-qa2:8983_solr": {
"responseHeader": {
"status": 0,
"QTime": 174
},
"response": {
"startTime": "2024-06-27T06:31:11.801540243Z",
"indexFileCount": 127,
"uploadedIndexFileCount": 0,
"indexSizeMB": 0.187,
"uploadedIndexFileMB": 0.0,
"shard": "shard1",
"endTime": "2024-06-27T06:31:11.974484159Z",
"shardBackupId": "md_shard1_2"
}
}
}
}

The API gives a success response but the backup is not getting created in one of the nodes.
The behaviour is not consistent. Sometimes it gets created in both the nodes and sometimes it gets created in only one.
Solr node 1

Solr node 2

I have tried issuing the API from the leader node.
What are the scenarios where backup maybe missing in one if the nodes and how do I ensure the backup gets created in both the nodes.

Did you just delete the old question with the information about only one copy being made per shard?

@MatsLindh  No I have not deleted it. It was in my staging ground and it automatically published it after 24 hours. So maybe that's why you are not seeing your comments.

@MatsLindh I could not reply to your comment because of the same reason I have mentioned in the above comment.
Thank you very much for your answer. It resolved a big doubt.

Ah, good point. I am apparently not aware of how the staging ground actually works. Thanks for answering!
